# Testing React component with TinyMCE Editor

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, ts-jest, tinymce-6

I have a component which utilizes tinyMCE Editor

```
<Editor 
id='tiny-editor'
tinymceScriptSrc={'/path'}
onInit={}
value={newVal}
init{{
height: 500,
menubar: true
}}
onEditorChange={handleCommentChange}
/>
```

I am trying to write a test and simulate a change on the editor. I was able to get the editor by document.querySelector('#tiny-editor). I was also able to set the value on the editor using userEvent.type(editor,'a') but I am not able to simulate the onEditorChange in order to trigger my handleCommentChange function.

I have tried:

```
fireEvent.change(editor, {target: {value: "<p>HI</p>"}})
```

I have tried:

```
editorInstance = tinymce.get(editor.id);
fireEvent.change(editorInstance, "value")
```

I have tried to create a customEvent

```
`const eventData = new CustomEvent('input', {
bubbles: true, 
cancelable: true,
detail: {
value
}}
}); 
fireEvent(editor, eventData);`
```

I have tried to do an editorInstance.setContent, editor.setValue